# Whats the difference between @google-cloud/firestore and firebase/firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Both packages don't seem to depend on each other but they not only seem to serve the same purpose but their types and functionality seem to be the same as well.

Why are they separate packages and which one should I use?

Links to the packages on github:

- [@google-cloud/firestore](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore)
- [firebase/firestore](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore)

Comment: Did you read the [README](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore#readme) of firestore? "This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the [officially supported firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) package. If you are developing a Node.js application that requires administrative access to Cloud Firestore, use the [@google-cloud/firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestoreV) Server SDK with your developer credentials."

Comment: I did. The question remains: why are they seperated? firebase/firestore could be a thin wrapper around google-cloud/firestore but instead they duplicated all the code and give you the same API and exports. Whats the reasoning behind this?

Comment: It would be really helpful to have an official response from Google here - variations like this are unsettling, especially when they're introduced without comment - eg [Schedule data exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export)